# "One of the provided arguments is not acceptable" when Sending a sharing invitation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Following this guide:

http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_invite

I do the following post request:

```
POST /v1.0/me/drive/items/01OL4PFB56Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ/invite 

Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0e....
Accept-Language: es-es

{
  "recipients": [
    {
      "email": "a-real-email@at-a-office365-account.com"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Here's the file that we're collaborating on.",
  "requireSignIn": true,
  "sendInvitation": true,
  "roles": [ "edit" ]
}
```

And I get this response code:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "One of the provided arguments is not acceptable.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "37c754c4-ace7-4582-9c6a-171633d1e335",
            "date": "2016-09-29T10:17:18"
        }
    }
}
```

This is just the example at the docs, but I tried with different values for email, removing message, sendInvitation=false, I get the same error. I don't understand what argument is incorrect.

UPDATE 1:

After changing 'edit' to 'write', I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "notAllowed",
    "message": "The action is not allowed by the system.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "644408df-05f6-4406-9503-b5c16da17976",
      "date": "2016-09-30T12:09:02"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The role should be `write` and not `edit` -- looks like we have a bug in the docs. Thanks for pointing this out! We'll get it fixed.

Comment: Very well. I changed to a 'write' instead of edit. I get a different error. I updated the answer.

Comment: Any idea why I would get a "The action is not allowed by the system." error?

Comment: Followed up offline--the second error came from trying to share the root folder rather than an item under it.